# Gardena battery rain water tank pump 2000/2 – SWD Interface

Tags: reverse-engineering, swd

I have a garden and would like to water it automatically with rain. For this I bought a «Gardena Battery Rain Water Tank Pump 2000/2» and would like to control via an ESP8266.

After opening the control panel, I found that the circuit board is molded in black plastic. I was able to remove the plastic from the circuit board.

There is an imprint on the board with the following pinout:

1. TX
2. GND
3. VSS
4. DAT
5. REST
6. CLK

I spent two days trying to identify the microcontroller.
[image: Front view]
[image: Rear view]

I found the Nuvoton NuMicro ML51TC0AE.
Datasheet: https://www.nuvoton.com/export/resource-files/DS_ML51_ML54_ML56_Series_EN_Rev2.02.pdf

I ordered a NU-Link from Taiwan and will now try to communicate with it via SWD.

I tried to talk to the microcontroller with the NuTool - PinView, however it does not go beyond "Detecting target device...". Unfortunately, when I use NuConsole, I get a timeout.

Actually, I would like to read the firmware.
Does anyone have experience in reverse engineering with Nuvoton 8051 chips and can give me a tip?

I still have an old post, but I don't think this one is seen anymore.
[Gardena battery rain water tank pump 2000/2 - UART interface](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/617385/)

Comment: please add new information to your first question, instead of posting a second question ... that will bump it to the top of the question stack

Comment: Usually it is easier to make your own device from scratch than to reverse engineer something like this, unless it's particularly advanced. Although it was nice of them to leave the debug header in place. In other words: throw out the circuit board entirely, and wire a relay module to your ESP8266, so that the relay allows the battery to power the motor

Comment: @jsotola I did not know that, thank you. I will do that next time.

Comment: @user253751 I have already designed and built my own controller, this one works too. However, the original control has great features that I would like to use. To build this is associated with considerable additional work.

Comment: You may be able to use an oscilloscope to see what the programmer is doing with the clock and data pins. (whether it seems to be communicating with the chip)

Comment: "Once programmed and verified, the programmed code can be protected by the Flash lock mechanism from being read out by external programming tool." - usually 99% of products do have this feature enabled which is one major reason that attempting to read firmware is usually a waste of time

Comment: @user253751 Thank you for your feedback. I will first try to read the pins Dat and Clk with a logic analizer.